# how to create dummy value for checkbox

Tags: jquery

i have the following jquery codes.
In the else loop, how can I create a dummy value for result as checkbox object? I need it to pass to another function for processing.Need to pass value as "All" if no checkbox selected.

```
var result = [];

$(".bf-c-1 input:checkbox").each(function() {

    //        //Do stuff
    if (this.checked) {
        $( "#checked_value" ).replaceWith( "<div id='checked_value_loading'></div>" );

        result = $("input[name='attribute_value[2][]']:checked");

        setTimeout(function() {
            displaySelectedFilter(result);
        }, 1000);

    }else{
        result[0] = "All" ;
        displaySelectedFilter(result);
    }
});
```

displaySelectorFilter function is:

```
function displaySelectedFilter(arr){

$( "#checked_value_loading" ).replaceWith( "<div class='column col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-5 col-md-5' id='checked_value'></div>" );

                $( "#checked_value" ).empty();

                $( "#checked_value" ).html( "Brand(s) <i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>&nbsp;" );


                arr.each(function (item) {
                var span = $("<span>");
                span.attr('class', 'selected_filter');
                span.text($(this)[0].value);
                $("#checked_value").append(span);
                });

}
```

Comment: It might be me, but it's not very clear what you're asking or what your problem is. So far as I can see, you already *are* setting the result to "all" and passing it.

Comment: please see the other displaySelectorFilter function above. the "span.text($(this)[0].value);" cannot grab a proper value if I pass the result as "All". it shows error msg in console.log as "TypeError: arr.each is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change `result[0] = "All" ;` to:

```
result = $('<input type="checkbox"  value="All"/>');
```